# Appending values to an array while scraping

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm pretty new to VBA so don't really know how to use arrays properly.

I am trying to add new values to an array as I'm scraping documents but don't know how to do this..

- The values I have are being scraped from 275 documents.
- I tried to write the values to the immediate window as it ran, which worked well, but only up to 200 lines.
- I would like to append 4 lines every time it runs through a file,
- one line for each variable `rfr`, `chief` ,etc....

The code:

```
Sub DeleteNotOpsSheet()
Dim fPath As String
Dim fName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim rfr As String, chief As String, yard As String, tp As String
Dim Output As ThisWorkbook

Dim i As Long
Dim spath As String
'Which folder?
fPath = "\\hofiler1\fileserver\users\AChan\Documents\Scrape\manning\SEP"
'Check if slash included
If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\'" Then
fPath = fPath & "\"
End If
'Check for xlsm files
fName = Dir(fPath & "*.XLS")
'Turn of the screen
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Loop until we run out of files

Do While fName <> ""
'Open the workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)

For Each xWs In wb.Worksheets

If xWs.Name = "ops sheet" Then '--> Getting an Object required error here

    rfr = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - Reefer Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("P42"))
    chief = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - Chief Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("V78"))
    yard = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - Yard Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AB74:AB81"))
    tp = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - TPC Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AB68"))

    'NEED HELP HERE: I would like to append these values to sheet1 on ThisWorkbook
    'Debug.Print rfr
    'Debug.Print chief
    'Debug.Print yard
    'Debug.Print tp

End If
wb.Save
wb.Close True

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'delete all the others

'SaveChanges:=True, Filename:=newName
'Increment count for feedback
i = i + 1
'Get next file name
fName = Dir()
Loop
'turn screen back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Give feedback
MsgBox "All done." & vbNewLine & "Number of files changed: " & i, vbOKOnly, "Run complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are serious about learning VBA you should watch this series: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5.  Here is a relevant video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&index=28&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the data to `sheet1` I would suggest:

a) Declare a variable to keep track of the row you are writing to

```
Dim rowOut As Long
```

b) Every time you go to write something to a new row, increment the variable

c) Either write each item to a single column, with a new row for each item

```
rowOut = rowOut + 1: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "A").Value = rfr
rowOut = rowOut + 1: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "A").Value = chief
rowOut = rowOut + 1: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "A").Value = yard
rowOut = rowOut + 1: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "A").Value = tp
```

or write each item to a different column on the same row

```
rowOut = rowOut + 1
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "A").Value = rfr
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "B").Value = chief
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "C").Value = yard
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowOut, "D").Value = tp
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use an array and collect all your strings and paste once. I wrote this without checking the syntax, so check it while writing the code in your file, however it shows the concept:

1-Define some variables:

```
Dim counter as long
Dim arr() as variant
```

2-Right before your loop:

```
counter=1
ReDim arr(1 to 4, 1 to counter)
```

3-inside the loop:

```
arr(1, counter)=rfr
arr(2, counter)=chief
arr(3, counter)=yard
arr(4, counter)=tp
counter=counter+1
ReDim Preserve arr(1 to 4, 1 to counter)
```

4-After the loop:

```
arr=Application.WorksheetFunctions.Transpose(arr)
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(Ubound(arr,1),Ubound(arr,2)).Value=arr
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function that I wrote a while back (full version with unit tests (which also show the usage) - follow github link [modArrayAppend.bas](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d319c66e4c9576a4c00eb27f0b3f6ae4)). It uses quadratic function to grow the array as needed (similar to dictionaries in Python), but you need to do one last `ReDim Preserve` to trim the array upon completion (this is really optional -- so that `UBound()` will return correct value).

```
' Simulates Collection's append() behaviour by keeping track of the last element's
' index and dynamically expanding the array using quadratic function (to minimize
' in-memory copy actions thus increasing performance significantly). Use this function
' when the number of elements to be appended is unknown.
'
' After all append operations are complete array's size needs to be adjusted to fit
' the contents exactly with ReDim Preserve expression:
'
'     ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To idx)
'
' After this idx may be reset.
'
' @param arr - dynamic array (can be unallocated or empty)
' @param idx - index of the last current element in arr. Initialize to any value at start.
'              It will be incremented by the append function and passed back by
'              reference. No special actions need to be done to maintain this element's
'              value current - just keep passing it to the append function. It is done
'              this way to keep arrayAppend() stateless (for the price of an extra argument).
' @param val - value to be appended to the array _after_ idx

Sub arrayAppend(arr As Variant, idx As Long, val As Variant)
    Dim size As Long
    If Not isArrayAllocated(arr) Then
        ' new un-allocated array - do initial sizing
        ReDim arr(idx To idx)
        arr(idx) = val
    Else
        ' existing array
        If idx >= UBound(arr) Then
            size = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
            If UBound(arr) + size > idx Then
                ' we're over the array's UBound - double the size
                ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) + size)
            Else
                ' if new index is far forward from the current UBound of the array
                ' take a bit of a conservative approach and extend the new array to
                ' idx + size
                ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) + (idx - UBound(arr)) + size)
            End If
        End If
        idx = idx + 1
        arr(idx) = val
    End If
End Sub


' Returns TRUE if the array is allocated (either a static array or a dynamic array that has been
' sized with Redim) or FALSE if the array is not allocated (a dynamic that has not yet
' been sized with Redim, or a dynamic array that has been Erased). Static arrays are always
' allocated.
'
' The VBA IsArray function indicates whether a variable is an array, but it does not
' distinguish between allocated and unallocated arrays. It will return TRUE for both
' allocated and unallocated arrays. This function tests whether the array has actually
' been allocated.
'
' This function is just the reverse of IsArrayEmpty.
'
' @see http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/isArrayAllocated.aspx
' @see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm

Public Function isArrayAllocated(arr As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim n As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    ' if Arr is not an array, return FALSE and get out.
    If IsArray(arr) = False Then
        isArrayAllocated = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Attempt to get the UBound of the array. If the array has not been allocated,
    ' an error will occur. Test Err.Number to see if an error occurred.
    n = UBound(arr, 1)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ' Under some circumstances, if an array is not allocated, Err.Number will be
        ' 0. To acccomodate this case, we test whether LBound <= Ubound. If this
        ' is True, the array is allocated. Otherwise, the array is not allocated.
        If LBound(arr) <= UBound(arr) Then
            ' no error. array has been allocated.
            isArrayAllocated = True
        Else
            isArrayAllocated = False
        End If
    Else
        ' error. unallocated array
        isArrayAllocated = False
    End If

End Function
```

P.S.: You can also use `Collection`. It has `.Add` method that allows you to just keep adding more and more values. Slight drawback of the collection is that for primitive types (strings, integers, etc.) it does some extra object/variant conversions and referencing, while the array will be generally slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to add another answer using VBA's standard `Collection` to do the same:

```
Option Explicit

Sub addStrings()

    ' create new empty collection
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim s As Variant

    ' keep adding as many strings as you wish
    c.Add "String1"
    c.Add "String2"
    c.Add "String3"
    c.Add "String4"

    ' when the time comes to process strings
    For Each s In c
        Debug.Print s
    Next s

End Sub
```

and the output:

```
String1
String2
String3
String4
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code saves each workbook each time it loops through a sheet (the `wb.Save` is inside the loop).

It actually doesn't look like you need to save the workbook at all.

This revised code:

- Writes your data to a csv file in the same path as the workbook collection you are using
- Stops looping through the sheets after `ops sheet` is found (as it cant happen a second time)
- Only saves the workbook if a change has been made. And even that seems unneccesary.

*code*

```
Sub DeleteNotOpsSheet()

Dim fPath As String
Dim fName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim rfr As String, chief As String, yard As String, tp As String
Dim Output As ThisWorkbook

Dim bVar As Boolean
Dim lFnum As Long

Dim i As Long


'Which folder?
'fPath = "\\hofiler1\fileserver\users\AChan\Documents\Scrape\manning\SEP"
fPath = "C:\temp\"
'Check if slash included
If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\'" Then
fPath = fPath & "\"
End If

lFnum = FreeFile
Open fPath & "dump.csv" For Output As lFnum


'Check for xlsm files
fName = Dir(fPath & "*.XLS")
'Turn of the screen

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
'Loop until we run out of files

Do While fName <> ""

'Open the workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)

For Each xWs In wb.Worksheets

If xWs.Name = "ops sheet" Then '--> Getting an Object required error here
    rfr = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - Reefer Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("P42"))
    chief = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - Chief Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("V78"))
    yard = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - Yard Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AB74:AB81"))
    tp = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 11) & " - TPC Foreman: " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AB68"))
    Print #lFnum, rfr & "," & chief & "," & yard & "," & "tp"
    bVar = True
    Exit For
End If
Next

If bVar Then wb.Save
wb.Close True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'delete all the others

'SaveChanges:=True, Filename:=newName
'Increment count for feedback
i = i + 1
'Get next file name
fName = Dir()
Loop

 Close lFnum

'turn screen back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Give feedback
MsgBox "All done." & vbNewLine & "Number of files changed: " & i, vbOKOnly, "Run complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: I originally intended for this to delete all the worksheets not named Ops Sheet and then extract from there and save it, but then decided I could just search for the worksheet and extract the ranges I want, it wasn't very well thought out and I had changed the way I wanted to do it and got lost (I'm not very good at this). Your revised code and suggestion works fast and beautifully though, thank you!